# Загрузить изображение с файловой системы в Bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Мне необходимо загрузить изображение андроид приложении с файловой системы в `bitmap`.

Перепробовал уже многое. Вот примеры того как я пробовал:

1. ```
   ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
   Bitmap bmp1 =image.getDrawingCache();
   ```
2. ```
   Bitmap bmp1 =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
   ```

Это некоторые из них. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как это сделать. В сети вменяемой информации по этому вопросу не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй способ вполне себе подходит, чем он вам не устраивает?

Comment: Во втором варианте требуется пермишен на чтение из файловой системы - может @boikov его не указывает?

Comment: Спасибо, я не указал.